# Unpainted Masyu

Tags: grid-deduction, masyu

[image]

> Exactly 3 of 7 circles here should be painted black to make the [Masyu](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/masyu.html) uniquely solved. Find them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found one solution, through some logical reasoning followed by trial and error.

> [image: Solutions]
>  **Ignore the bottom left figure**
>  I first figured that the circle in position [2, 1] (Red) must be white, because if it were black, circle in position [1, 3] (Green) would not be able to connect. Then for similar reasons, the yellow and cyan ones can not both be black. The same is true for cyan and purple. A few more similar deductions, like blue, purple, and black can not all be black, left me with eight possible arrangements, so I just tried to solve them all. Only one of them has a solution, and the process of solving it showed that it is unique (I don't know how to prove that though)

Thanks to Skynet_0 for pointing out that one of my solutions is invalid.

Comment: Your left solution seems to have an error in the leftmost black circle and the rightmost white.

Comment: @Skynet_0 Thanks, I don't know how I missed that...

Comment: Very well done! :D